# How can I associate a single record with one or more PKs

Tags: database, t-sql

If I had a single record that represented, say, a sellable item:

```
ItemID | Name
-------------
101    | Chips
102    | Candy bar
103    | Beer
```

I need to create a relationship between these items and one or more different types of PKs. For instance, a company might have an inventory that included chips; a store might have an inventory that includes chips and a candy bar, and the night shift might carry chips, candy bars, and beer. The is that we have different kinds of IDs: CompanyID, StoreID, ShiftID respectively.

My first though was "Oh just create link tables that link Company to inventory items, Stores to inventory items, and shifts to inventory items" and that way if I needed to look up the inventory collection for any of those entities, I could query them explicitly. However, the UI shows that I should be able to compile a list arbitrarily (e.g. show me all inventory items for company a, all west valley stores and Team BrewHa who is at an east valley store) and then display them grouped by their respective entity:

```
Company A
---------
- Chips

West Valley 1
-------------
- Chips
- Candy Bar

West Valley 2
-------------
- Chips

BrewHa (East Valley 6)
--------------------
- Chips
- Candy Bar
- Beer
```

So again, my first though was to base the query on the provided information (what kinds of IDs did they give me) and then just union them together with some extra info for grouping (candidate keys like IDType+ID) so that the result looked kind of like this:

```
IDType | ID | InventoryItemID
------------------------------
1      |100 | 1
2      |200 | 1
2      |200 | 2
2      |201 | 1
3      |300 | 1
3      |300 | 2
3      |300 | 3
```

I guess this would work, but it seems incredibly inefficient and contrived to me; I'm not even sure how the parameters of that sproc would work... So my question to everyone is: is this even the right approach? Can anyone explain alternative or better approaches to solve the problem of creating and managing these relationships?

Comment: This sounds like a case of poor database design. Is there a reason you can't just put companies, stores, and shifts into the same table, say "Carrier"? The Carrier table could then have a TypeID = 0, 1, or 2, corresponding to a company, a store, or a shift, respectively.

Comment: I *think* I follow what you're saying. Do you have a more complete example?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to ascertain what you want as I don't know the purpose/use of this data. I'm not well-versed in normalization, but perhaps a star schema might work for you. Please keep in mind, I'm using my best guess for the terminology. What I was thinking would look like this:

**tbl_Current_Inventory**(Fact Table) records current Inventory

```
InventoryID  INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Inventory(ID),
CompanyID    INT     NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Company(ID),
StoreID      INT     NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Store(ID),
ShiftID      INT     NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Shift(ID),
Shipped_Date DATE --not really sure, just an example,
CONSTRAINT clustered_unique CLUSTERED(InventoryID,CompanyID,StoreID,ShiftID)
```

**tbl_Inventory**(Fact Table 2)

```
ID NOT NULL INT,
ProductID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Product(ID),
PRIMARY KEY(ID,ProductID)
```

**tbl_Store**(Fact Table 3)

```
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CompanyID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Company(ID),
RegionID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_Region(ID)
```

**tbl_Product**(Dimension Table)

```
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Product_Name VARCHAR(25)
```

**tbl_Company**(Dimension Table)

```
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Company_Name VARCHAR(25)
```

**tbl_Region**(Dimension Table)

```
ID PRIMARY KEY,
Region_Name VARCHAR(25)
```

**tbl_Shift**(Dimension Table)

```
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Shift_Name VARCHAR(25)
Start_Time TIME,
End_Time TIME
```

So a little explanation. Each dimension table holds only distinct values like **tbl_Region**. Lists each region's name once and an ID.

Now for **tbl_Current_Inventory**, that will hold all the columns. I have companyID and StoreID both in their for a reason. Because this table can hold company inventory information(NULL StoreID and NULL shiftID) AND it can hold Store Inventory information.

Then as for querying this, I would create a view that joins each table, then simply query the view. Then of course there's indexes, but I don't think you asked for that. Also notice I only had like one column per dimension table. My guess is that you'll probably have more columns then just the name of something.

Overall, this helps eliminate a lot of duplicate data. And strikes a good balance at performance and not overly complicated data structure. Really though, if you slap a view on it, and query the view, it should perform quite well especially if you add some good indexes.

This may not be a perfect solution or even the one you need, but hopefully it at least gives you some ideas or some direction.

If you need any more explanation or anything else, just let me know.

Comment: Store belongs to a company.  Repeating CompanyID in tbl_Current_Inventory is not 3NF.

Comment: Yes that is correct, BUT you will notice the OP says Companies can have Inventory and stores can have inventory. So if a row has a store inventory then CompanyID will be null and vice versa. It's for simplicity's sake. The OP could split each table one for company inventory and one for store inventory

Comment: But your table has CompanyID INT NOT NULL.  What Company or Store  design does is stop you from creating a PK on that table - you could not stop duplicate entries.

Comment: Okay I changed CompanyID to INT NULL, but as far as this primary key issue, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you expound a bit more?

Comment: See my Inventory table.  That composite PK is not just efficient but it would prevent duplicate entries.    You cannot have a nullable column in the PK.

Comment: Yes but you can create clustered unique constraint which is quite similar

Comment: Just because you can does not mean you should

Comment: Well it's really not much different from a primary key. A primary key is type of unique constraint that doesn't allow NULL and by default creates a clustered index. So my solution is the same as a primary key except that it allows NULL

Comment: I know what PK is.  You did not not state unique.  Your solution would allow both a StoreID and CompanyID.  Your solution is not 3NF.  You can learn or argue - you decide.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't mean to argue. I think this is just a misunderstanding. And I know my solution is not 3NF. I don't believe star schema's are meant to be 3NF. To me, my solution is trying to find a balance between performance and simplicity

Answer (score 0):

In a normalized database, you implement a many-to-many relationship by creating a table that defines the relationships between entities just as you thought initially.  It might seem contrived, but it gives you the functionality you need.  In your case I would create a table for the relationship called something like "Carries" with the primary key of (ProductId, StoreId, ShiftId).  Sometimes you can break normalization rules for performance, but it comes with side effects.

I recommend picking up a good book on designing relational databases.  Here's a starter on a few topics:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score -1):

You need to break it down to inventory belongs to a store and a shift
Inventory does does not belong to a company - a store belongs to a company
If the company holds inventory directly then I would create a store name warehouse
A store belongs to a region
Don't design for the UI - put the data in 3NF

Tables:

```
Company   ID, name    
Store     ID, name 
Region    ID, name   
Product   ID, name   
Shift     ID, name 

CompanyToStore  CompanyID, StoreID          (composite PK)

RegionToStore   RegionID, StoreID           (composite PK)

Inventory       StoreID, ShiftID, ProductID (composite PK)
```

The composite PK are not just efficient they prevent duplicates
The join tables should have their own ID as  PK
Let the relationships they are managing be the PK

If you want to report by company across all shifts you would have a query like this

```
select distinct store.Name, Product.Name 
  from Inventory 
  join Store 
    on Inventory.StoreID = Store.ID 
  join CompanyToStore 
    on Store.ID = CompanyToStore.StoreID 
   and CompanyToStore.CompanyID = X
```

store count in a region

```
select RegionName, count(*) 
  from RegionToStore 
  join Region 
    on Region.ID = RegionToStore.RegionID 
 group by RegionName
```